# Pygame: Timer For Time Alive

Tags: python, timer, pygame

Hello I am currently making a game in python and I am trying to make a timer which I have never attempted before, hence asking this question. What I really need to know is how to loop this small area where it says #Timer. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

```
import pygame, time
import pygame.mixer
from bullet import Bullet
from constants import DIR_LEFT, DIR_RIGHT

# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, gravity):
        pygame.mixer.init()

        # Player dimensions and position

        # Player image and animation
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/player.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/player2.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball1.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball2.png'))
        self.maxImage = len(self.images)
        self.currentImage = 0

        self.jumpSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/jump.ogg')
        self.shootSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/laser.ogg')

        #~ self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 80, 80)
        self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.timeTarget = 10
        self.timeNum = 0

        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0

        self.health = 200
        self.score = 0
        self.alivetime = 0
        self.second = 1000

        self.direction = DIR_RIGHT

        # Jump and gravity
        self.jumping = False
        self.on_ground = False
        self.origJumpVel = 15
        self.jumpVel = self.origJumpVel
        self.gravity = 0.5

    # Jump inputs
    def do_jump(self):
        if self.jumping and not self.on_ground:
            self.velY = -self.jumpVel
            self.jumpVel -= self.gravity

        if self.on_ground:
            self.jumping = False
            self.jumpVel = self.origJumpVel
            self.velY = 0
            self.on_ground = True

    def handle_events(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.jumpSound.play(0)
                if not self.jumping:
                    self.jumping = True
                    self.on_ground = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                self.shootSound.play(0)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                #pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.currentImage], False, False)
                self.velX = -5

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                #pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.currentImage], True, False)
                self.velX = +5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                self.velX = 0

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                bullet.velX = 0

    # PLayer updates
    def update(self):

        #self.timeNum += 1
        # Animations
        #if self.direction == DIR_LEFT:
            #if self.timeNum == self.timeTarget:
                    #self.currentImage += 1
                #if self.currentImage >= self.maxImage:
                    #self.currentImage = 0
                #self.timeNum = 0

        # Timer
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= self.second:
            self.alivetime = +1
            pygame.time.get_ticks() == 0

        # Screen wrap
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.rect.left = 0

        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.right = 1280

        if self.velX < 0 and self.direction != DIR_RIGHT: # Moving right
            self.direction = DIR_RIGHT
            self.images[self.currentImage] = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.currentImage], True, False)

        elif self.velX > 0 and self.direction != DIR_LEFT: # Moving left
            self.direction = DIR_LEFT
            self.images[self.currentImage] = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.currentImage], True, False)

    # Player rendering
    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.images[self.currentImage], self.rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `player.update()` in mainloop in every loop and Timer will loop too.

**By The Way:**

if you try to set tick to zero in this

```
pygame.time.get_ticks() == 0
```

than you are wrong. You can't change number of ticks.

Use this

```
# __init__()

    self.time_to_change_alivetime = pygame.time.get_ticks() + self.second

# update()

    if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= self.time_to_change_alivetime:
        self.alivetime += 1
        self.time_to_change_alivetime += self.second
```

or this (without `if`)

```
# __init__()

    self.start_alivetime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# update()

    self.alivetime = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_alivetime) / self.second
```

or more precisely (1 minute = 60 seconds = 60 000 milliseconds)

```
# __init__()

    self.start_alivetime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# update()

    milliseconds = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_alivetime

    self.alivetime_minutes = milliseconds / 60000 
    self.alivetime_seconds = (milliseconds % 60000) / self.second
    self.alivetime_milliseconds = milliseconds % self.second
```